# Swipe to dismiss in dynamically updated recycler view

Tags: android, dynamic, swipe, android-recyclerview, drag

So I have switched to Recycler View and used ItemTouchHelper to add the ability to move and dismiss items.

However all items in my recycler view update every second. So if you are in a process of dragging items around and update happens the animation resets.

Is there an easy way to disable updates OR, even better, disable repositioning of recycler view items after notifyDataSetChanged() is called?

How I update Recycler View: I have a Timer object that calls notifyDataSetChanged(); every second.

Comment: why do you need this intensive notifyDataSetChanged() every second? smells no good to me.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Well, i need to redraw **every view** in recyclerView every second (a countdown app), I found that notifyDataSetChanged works pretty well. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

1. Added "boolean moving" to the my custom recyclerview adapter class that is set to "true" every time any item is being dragged\swiped
2. Timer now calls my custom method adapter.update() instead of adapter.notifyDataChanged()

   public void update() {
           if (!moving) notifyDataSetChanged();
       }

It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

can you avoid invoking notifyDataSetChanged when dragging?